# Argument of type '{ description: string; siteurl: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, reactjs

For SPFx running gulp serve getting below error. For this line it was working before:

```
public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IReactGetitemsProps > = React.createElement(
        ReactGetitems,{
            description: escape(this.properties.description), 
            siteurl: escape(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl)
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because you are missing one property in `IReactGetitemsProps.ts` file. I am guessing you are missing `siteurl` property in your file.

It should be something like:

```
export interface IReactGetitemsProps {
   description: string;
   siteurl: string;
}
```

Comment: its there its working till yesterday

Comment: it working now thank you for the help

Comment: Welcome. Glad it worked for you :)